# "Merging" columns from several tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008, suppose I have several tables with 3 common columns (not related):

TABLE1

```
col1 colSomeOther col2 colAnotherOne
```

TABLE2

```
col1 colSomeOther col2 colAnotherOne
```

TABLE3

```
col1 colSomeOther col2 colAnotherOne
```

I would like to create a view which merges col1 and 2 for the 3 tables above. Something like:

VIEW

```
col1   col2
```

where col1 contains **ALL elements** from table 1, 2 and 3, and col2 contains ALL elements from col2 in table 1, 2, 3.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. This is a "union"; multiple result sets of the same "signature" (number and type of data columns), concatenated one after the other. The query to do this is as simple as:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2 FROM TABLE2
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2 FROM TABLE3
```

If you want the query to "de-duplicate" the results, returning only unique rows, omit the "ALL" keywords from the unions. With the ALL keywords, it simply tacks on the results of each SELECT to the combined result set, including rows from Table2 that may have exactly the same data as Table1.

Comment: And if you want to create a view from this, do `CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT ...`

Comment: Ah yes, I'd forgotten that the OP asked for a "view".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for an `UNION`:

```
select col1, col2 from table1
UNION ALL
select col1, col2 from table2
UNION ALL
select col1, col2 from table3
```

Should work as long as `col1` and `col2` have compatible data types across all three tables.

If you want to eliminate duplicate rows then use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.